# How to correct my C custom printf( ) code

Tags: c

I have a problem with the output of my custom printf code when I use 4 or more arguments, and I can't find out where is the problem

```
 ` #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdarg.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int _printf(const char *format, ...);

   int main()
   {
       _printf("%c%cth %s%s a%cg%s: Y%sou %s no%ching%s Snow.%c", 'W', 'i', "some ", "more", 'r', "s", "", "know", 't', ", Jon", '\n');
   }

   /**
    * _printf - Custum printf function
    * @format: A string containing the caracters to print
    * Return: the count of the printed charecters
    */

    int _printf(const char *format, ...)
    {
       va_list args;                                                                                                                                  
       int count = 0;                                                                                                                                 
       int i, j, length = 0;                                                                                                                          
       char c, *p, *ptr;                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                
       va_start(args, format);                                                                                                                        
       if (format == NULL)                                                                                                                            
               return (-1);                                                                                                                           
       for (i = 0; format[i] != '\0'; i++)                                                                                                            
       {                                                                                                                                              
              if (format[i] == '%')                                                                                                                  
              {                                                                                                                                      
                    i++;                                                                                                                           
                    if (format[i] == 'c')                                                                                                          
                    {                                                                                                                              
                            c = va_arg(args, int);                                                                                                 
                            count += write(1, &c, 1);                                                                                              
                    }                                                                                                                              
                    if (format[i] == 's')                                                                                                          
                    {                                                                                                                              
                            ptr = va_arg(args, char*);                                                                                             
                            if (ptr == NULL)
                               count += write(1, "(null)", 6);
                            else
                            {
                                while (*ptr != '\0')
                                {
                                     length++;
                                     ptr++;
                                 }
                                p = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
                                for (j = 0; j < (length + 1); j++)
                                   p[length - j] = *(ptr - j);
                                count += write(1, p, length);
                                free(p);
                             }
                    }                                                                                                                                                              
                    if (format[i] == '%')                                                                                                          
                            count += write(1, &format[i], 1);                                                                                      
            }                                                                                                                                      
            else                                                                                                                                   
                    count += write(1, &format[i], 1);                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                              
    va_end(args);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return (count);                                                                                                                                
   }  `
```

for example when I try to test my function in the main code like this:

`_printf("%c%cth %s%s a%cg%s: Y%sou %s no%ching%s Snow.%c", 'W', 'i', "some ", "more", 'r', "s", "", "know", 't', ", Jon", '\n');`

expected out put is :

With some more args: You know nothing, Jon Snow.

What I get :

With some more argonknows: Y Jonknowou .%c, Jonknow nothinging%s Snow.%c, Jon Snow.

Comment: The expected and observed results are identical.

Comment: Please update the question to include a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a `main` function and all user-defined headers (what is `#include "main.h"`?). Please verify your expected vs. actual output is correct, and please format it in a way that removes any ambiguity from the question.

Comment: Please use consistent indentation for code.  If it's not readable, it's not readable *even for you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these issues:

**Incorrect length determination**

`while (*ptr != '\0') { length++; ptr++; }` does not start with `length = 0`, except for the first time it is used.

**Code sets the *null character***

`for (j = 0; j < (length + 1); j++) p[length - j] = *(ptr - j);`  populates `p[]` with the *null character*.  Not needed.

**Allocation not needed**

---

Instead:

```
  if (format[i] == 's') {
    const char *ptr = va_arg(args, char*);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      ptr = "(null)";
    }
    size_t length;
    for (length = 0; ptr[length]; length++) {
      ;
    }
    count += write(1, ptr, length);
  }
```